# How to speed up a SQLAlchemy Query?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a table of over 10 million rows. There are roughly 50+ columns. The table stores sensors data/parameters. Let's say that I need to query data for the whole day or 86,400 seconds. It would need take roughly 20 or more seconds to complete this query.

I have added individual indices on a few columns such as recordTimestamp(that store when the data is captured), deviceId(the identification of the sensor), positionValid(whether GPS geolocation is valid). Then I added a composite index which includes all three columns.

Below is my query:

```
t1 = time.time()
conn = engine.connect()
select_statement = select([Datatable]).where(and_(
    Datatable.recordTimestamp >= start_date,
    Datatable.recordTimestamp <= end_date,
    Datatable.deviceId == device_id,
    Datatable.positionValid != None,
    Datatable.recordTimestamp % query_interval == 0))
lol_data = conn.execute(select_statement).fetchall()    
conn.close() 
t2 = time.time()
time_taken = t2 - t1
print('Select: ' + time_taken)
```

Below is my EXPLAIN ANALYZE statement:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT datatable.id, datatable."createdAt", datatable."analogInput01", datatable."analogInput02", datatable."analogInput03", datatable."analogInput04", datatable."analogInput05", datatable."analogInput06", datatable."analogInput07", datatable."canEngineRpm", datatable."canEngineTemperature", datatable."canFuelConsumedLiters", datatable."canFuelLevel", datatable."canVehicleMileage", datatable."deviceId", datatable."deviceTemperature", datatable."deviceInternalVoltage", datatable."deviceExternalVoltage", datatable."deviceAntennaCut", datatable."deviceEnum", datatable."deviceVehicleMileage", datatable."deviceSimSignal", datatable."deviceSimStatus", datatable."iButton01", datatable."iButton02", datatable."recordSequence", datatable."recordTimestamp", datatable."accelerationAbsolute", datatable."accelerationBrake", datatable."accelerationBump", datatable."accelerationTurn", datatable."accelerationX", datatable."accelerationY", datatable."accelerationZ", datatable."positionAltitude", datatable."positionDirection", datatable."positionSatellites", datatable."positionSpeed", datatable."positionLatitude", datatable."positionLongitude", datatable."positionHdop", datatable."positionMovement", datatable."positionValid", datatable."positionEngine" FROM datatable WHERE datatable."recordTimestamp" >= 1519744521 AND datatable."recordTimestamp" <= 1519745181 AND datatable."deviceId" = '864495033990901' AND datatable."positionValid" IS NOT NULL AND datatable."recordTimestamp" % 1 = 0;
```

Below is the result from EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the SELECT:

```
Index Scan using "ix_dataTable_recordTimestamp" on dataTable (cost=0.44..599.35 rows=5 width=301) (actual time=0.070..10.487 rows=661 loops=1)
Index Cond: (("recordTimestamp" >= 1519744521) AND ("recordTimestamp" <= 1519745181))
Filter: (("positionValid" IS NOT NULL) AND (("deviceId")::text = '864495033990901'::text) AND (("recordTimestamp" % 1) = 0))
Rows Removed by Filter: 6970
Planning time: 0.347 ms
Execution time: 10.658 ms
```

Whereas below is the result from time taken calculated by Python:

```
Select:  47.98712515830994 
JSON:  0.19731807708740234
```

Below is my code profiling:

```
10302 function calls (10235 primitive calls) in 12.612 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000   12.595   12.595 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:882(execute)
    1    0.000    0.000   12.595   12.595 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:267(_execute_on_connection)
    1    0.000    0.000   12.595   12.595 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1016(_execute_clauseelement)
    1    0.000    0.000   12.592   12.592 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1111(_execute_context)
    1    0.000    0.000   12.590   12.590 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:506(do_execute)
    1   12.590   12.590   12.590   12.590 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py:1113(fetchall)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.017    0.017 /Users/afeezaziz/Projects/Bursa/backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py:1080(_fetchall_impl)
    1    0.008    0.008    0.017    0.017 {method 'fetchall' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
```

Comment: The query finished in 10 milliseconds.. Can you provide an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the slow query instead?

Comment: I am not sure why using directly would give this... although I added print(time.time()) above the start of connection and end of connection and this is the result: Select:  10.030901908874512 so according to print statement, it is roughly 10 seconds.

Comment: A good visualization for „on CPU“ analysis are [flamegraphs](https://github.com/evanhempel/python-flamegraph/blob/master/README.rst).  Try to give them a shot to see the most busy code path. From the measures you show I would guess that „converting into python objects“ eats up time. How big is the dataset in kB?

Comment: Yes, the one taking too much time is converting into python objects. The dataset after being received is roughly 1-3MB.

What are my options?

Comment: Unless you really need all raw data, you might execute already some analytics on the database itself and return only the results of the aggregation. Or if you need to process the data row by row, you might be able to do it without fetching all rows, but on the fly. Basically, need more context in order to give some more ideas.

Comment: Need to produce full raw data as it will be sent in CSV back, part of business logic of the app. What sort of context or further explanation that you need?

Comment: Thanks @van ,  I also experimented with fetchmany and fetchone. By using fetchmany I have reduced the query time by 5 seconds. Now instead of 'execute' taking a long time, this particular {method 'fetchmany' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects} takes 30-40 seconds.

Comment: What order are the columns in the composite index? That affects how it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Postgres built in [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) or if your really need to retrieve the result in Python (e.g. you can't write to disk directly via COPY) you can use COPY via psycopgs [copy_expert](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) function:

```
cur = conn.cursor()

outputquery = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(query)

with open('resultsfile', 'w') as f:
    cur.copy_expert(outputquery, f)

conn.close()
```

This should avoid serialization all together.

Answer (score -1):

- According to your query and your index, I think that you already tried to do the best because your query concerns about `"recordTimestamp"`, `"deviceId"` and `"positionValid"`, so, just make sure that you already created the index from 3 columns.
- I think the problem is in "`select([Datatable])`", I guess you select all the columns, so, as your description, with 50+ columns, it takes time to parse data and send data to client. To more clear, adding the index just helps your "executing time" (time to find the result) but doesn't help your "fetching time" (when you run "lol_data = conn.execute(select_statement).fetchall()").
- Solution: If you don't want to change the structure of table, you just select the columns you need. But spliting the table into 2 tables is better. 1 tables includes the parameters and others contains the `"deviceId"`, `"recordTimestamp"`, value. And you can change the `"deviceId"` by using index (comparing and sending string takes more time than using integer).

Comment: I have tried with select([Datatable.recordTimestamp, Datatable.deviceId]) , the query time is roughly the same.

I have experimented with deviceId in the integer form, unfortunately the same query tune.

Comment: Yes, because your database does the same things: get data each row and parse it, but just send 2 columns, so, it can save a little bit time when you receive data but not the time when you parse data. 50+ columns are very large, if you maintain this form, you already do the best with query (create the BTREE index from 3 columns, not HASH index because the HASH index concerns about the address not values). I am working with a table 200 millions records and only 4 columns: count, deviceID, datetime and value. It takes only 8 seconds to retrieve data in a month (about 30 thousands rows).

Answer (score -1):

> SQLAlchemy is just the connector to the database, the whole query runs at the end of the database.

Optimizing the query with the help of Procedures and SQLAlchemy, you can archive it.
Here is a good read which can optimize your way of using.
[SQLAlchemy collection docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit)

If you are using MySQL database, you should also try MySQLdb API which is a bit faster then SQLAlchemy because MySQLdb is specifically object-oriented for the MySQL operations and iterations.